# C# Generics containing generics? T<TValue>

Tags: c#, generics

I got lost implementing a interface where I need `TKey`, `TValue` and `TMessageListener`

```
public interface IHelper<TKey, TValue, TMessageListener>
```

but my `TMessageListener` is `TMessageListener<TValue>` how can I declare this at the interface layer?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by _TMessageListener is TMessageListener< TValue >_?  Are you saying `TMessageListener` is maybe a `IEnumerble<TValue>`?  It doesn't make sense for a generic type to have a generic type attached to it like that.

Comment: It occurs that TMessageListener is not a IEnumerable but a interface that implements a class that receives TValue as parameter.

Comment: Then you'll want to express that as a constraint `where TMessageListener : IYourInterface<TValue>`.  Also you should update the question to clearly state that `TMessageListener` is suppose to implement an generic interface that takes `TValue` as it's generic type.

Comment: So in the end i have to infer the type of my interface? I was expecting other way. But thanks! Put this as answer :)

Answer (score 3):

It could be achieved with type constraints as follows.

```
public interface IHelper<TKey,TValue,TMsgLst> where TMsgLst : TMessageListener<TValue>
```

Comment: This is confusing if `TMessageListener` is a generic type, which seems to be the case.

Comment: How is this confusing? I think this is exactly how it should be done. ...CODE THE DOOR!

Comment: That was the first thing that i did, but TMessageListener is generic and it gets compile error.

Comment: @Abbondanza It's confusing because `TMessageListener` is not an actual type, but a generic, so this won't work.  Now I'm not saying that the problem cannot be solved with constraints.  I'm saying the question is not clear enough to give a good answer.